# Python - Convertir float en string

Tags: python, string, matrices, numpy, conversión-de-tipos

Tengo una matriz de floats de 3000 por 17, el tema es que en la primer columna quiero guardar strings.

Con el siguiente código:

```
tabla = numpy.empty((3000, 17))

nombres = ['i0{i}_0{d}_{n}.bmp'.format(i = imagen, d = distorsion, n = 
nivel) for imagen in range(1,26) for distorsion in range(1,25) for 
nivel in range(1,6)]

tabla[:, 0] = nombres
```

Obviamente python da el siguiente error:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'i01_01_1.bmp'
```

Pero yo no quiero convertir los strings en float, sino guardar strings en ESA columna, en el resto de la matriz tendré valores float.

Espero puedan ayudarme.

Desde ya muchas gracias.

Saludos.

Lucía

Comment: ¿Donde están los `float`s?

Comment: no entiendo tu pregunta

Comment: No entiendo _tu_ pregunta...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tienes un array bidimensional

```
a=[[1,2,3],[2,3,4],[3,4,5]]
```

tienes un array unidimensional

```
b=['bar','foo','car']
```

y cambias el primer valor de cada una por el valor en b

```
for x in a[:]:
    x[0]=b[a.index(x)]

[['bar', 2, 3], ['foo', 3, 4], ['car', 4, 5]]
```

aplicado en tu ejemplo

```
a=tabla.tolist()
for x in a[:]:
        x[0]=nombres[a.index(x)]
print a
```

Comment: Sale el siguiente error: AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'index'

Comment: tiene que convertir el ndarray en list `tabla.tolist()`

Comment: ahora funcionó, gracias! :)

Answer (score 0):

Usa dtype=object. Creo que con esto funciona:

```
tabla = numpy.empty((3000, 17), dtype=object)
```

Si quieres usar numpy y mezclar floats con strings necesitas usar matrices estructuradas. Mira [aquí](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.rec.html) o [aquí](https://web.archive.org/web/20181104192106/http://www.doctormetrics.com:80/2017/02/23/importando-datos-en-python/).

Comment: pero solo en esa columna quiero strings, los otros tienen que ser floats...

Comment: lo probé y no funciona...

Comment: Si quieres mezclar strings y floats usa matrices estructuradas. Mira aquí   https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.rec.html o aquí http://www.doctormetrics.com/2017/02/23/importando-datos-en-python/

Comment: Deberías agregar estos informaciones adicionales a tu respuesta (editandolo)